# Placing a component at the location of a click on another component

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am displaying pages of a PDF using react-pdf in my application. I have a button called 'add marking', which when clicked, should give the ability to add a mark (small circle component) on the PDF page at the location where I click.

I'm confused with how I should be approaching the problem. I am particularly stuck with what is the best way to get the x and y coordiantes of the click on the pdf. I want the mark to be the same wrt the pdf at all times.

Comment: Hi @Zag, could you add more information to your question such as your current code snippets?

Comment: If you are looking to determine the coordinates of an event object (which will be passed by the click event) you may want to use this API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect Otherwise, more detail would help, as tobias said.

Comment: Hi thank you for the comments. I created a new question after trying some different approaches, would be great if you could check that out. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556096/how-to-position-components-to-the-location-of-a-mouse-click-in-react